# Saving .swp/.un~ files to subdirectories

Tags: save, filesystem, options, git, undo-redo

Is there any way to save these files to automatically created subdirs? Google gave me no answers.

The reason is simple- I work on several computers which I keep synced via git, so having these files in the same directory structure is practical to me. If all these files could be in a single subfolder of the repo's root for extra neatness it'd be great, but just having a /.vimfiles folder in each directory wouldn't be bad either.

Comment: Are you wanting to sync the swap files, or have git ignore them? Theres a difference in how to accomplish one or the other.

Comment: I want to keep them synced, *but* at the time of making this ask forgot that files in .git are ignored automatically. Editing to avoid confusion.

Comment: Out of the box vim won't do the per-repo subdir. Also, when you specify a directory for swapfiles it has to exist. It it were me I'd create a shell script "wrapper" for vim that does these things and alias `vim` to that. Or perhaps use autocommands (not sure off the top of my head if an event comes early enough to create swap dirs before vim complains).

Comment: You can actually make the directory in your vimrc before setting; i do this with undodir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**:

Use the `mkdir()` function to create those subdirectories and then set `undodir`, `backupdir` and `directory` to tell vim to use them. This snippet of code should work just fine:

```
function! Mkdir(path)
    if !isdirectory(resolve(a:path))
        try
            call mkdir(a:path, "p", 0775)
        catch
            return ''
        endtry
    endif
    return a:path
endfunction

" Find the nearest .git directory
let s:repo_root = ''
let s:cwd = getcwd()
while getcwd() != '/'
    if isdirectory('.git')
        let s:repo_root = getcwd()
        break
    endif
    cd ..
endwhile
exec 'cd '.s:cwd

" If we found a .git/ directory somewhere, create directories there
if s:repo_root != ''
    set undofile
    set backup
    set swapfile

    let s:dirpath = s:repo_root."/.vimfiles"
    let &undodir = Mkdir(s:dirpath."/undo")
    let &backupdir = Mkdir(s:dirpath."/backup")
    let &directory = Mkdir(s:dirpath."/swp")
endif
```

**Long answer**

It's probably not a good idea to sync those files with git. Keep in mind that they will be constantly changing, and that will add a lot of clutter to your commits. Also there is no point in syncing `.swp` files, since the whole point of having `.swp` files is to avoid having two instances of the editor working on the same file at once. If you are syncing between different machines, these files stop making any sense.

I would suggest you don't put those files under your projects directory, but rather save them in subdirectories inside `~/.vim`. In that case you only have to slightly modify the snippet above to remove the `.git/` discovery part, and to replace `s:dir_path` with `~/.vim/`

Comment: I don't do constant syncronization -or even use this for actual code- but instead move between my laptop and desktop constantly. Git is the best way I have to keep files synced between both of those and my USB. And keeping .swp files is a better idea than it might seem- remember they act as restoration points if vim closes unexpectedly.

Comment: @DudeForrealsies I don't see it that way, but whatever works for you. At least I hope the code helps you out

Comment: Hm, this seems to only work if I start gvim in the same directory as the file, such as "gvim . 1.md", but it does what I want nonetheless.